# In this sample, are the two events independent?

Tags: probability, statistics

This equation comes from Edgenuity's course of Statistics, and I am taking the course as a high school senior. I understand that for two events to be independent, $P(A) = P(A|B)$. I also know how to find $P(B|A)$. I attempt to do this in my solving of the problem below:

**According to a recent survey of adults, approximately 62% carry cash on a regular basis. The adults were also asked if they have children. Of the 46% who have children, 85% carry cash on a regular basis. Is carrying cash independent from having children in this sample?**

First, I assume $P(A)$ is alike to $P$(carrying cash), which would equal $0.62$. $P(A|B)$ then is alike to $P$(carrying cash|having children). I am unsure of how to find this second probability. I divided $P$(carrying cash and having children), which was assumed to be $0.2852$ when multiplying $0.62$ and $0.46$, by $P$(carrying cash), which is $0.62$. If my method was correct, then $P$(carrying cash|having children) $= 0.46$, and my conclusion would then be that carrying cash is not independent from having children in this sample because $0.46 ≠ 0.62$. Are my methods and answer correct? If not, please explain why.

Comment: $P(C|K) =.85 \ne .62 = P(C),$ so not independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the events were independent, then $62$% of those having children would carry cash.  Since $85$% of them carry cash, the events are not independent.